# RxJava Asynchronous debouncing

Tags: rx-java

Using RxJava operations, is it possible to "ignore" elements that have been processed in the downstream if the upstream emits new items?

for example

```
Observable.create(...)
  .flatMap(...) // 30 seconds to process (Asynchronous)
  .flatMap(...) // 30 seconds to process (Asynchronous)
  etc...
```

what I need to achieve is if the upstream notify about the new item it will cancel any operation on the stream below that is currently running even if the down stream doing something in other thread asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `flatMap()` operator, you can use `switchMap()`. When a new value is received in `switchMap()`, the old observable is unsubscribed and a replacement observable is subscribed.

```
Observable.create( ... )
  .switchMap( value -> getObservable1( value )
                         .switchMap( value2 -> getObservable2( value2 ) )
  ...
```

If you want observers further downstream to also be cancelled, you will have to propagate the `switchMap()`. In the code above, an emission in the first stage of the observer chain will unsubscribe from `getObservable1( value )` and from `getObservable2( value2 )`.